# How can I print a recurrent label for x lines?

Tags: python

I need to print a label next to my samples.
I have 96 samples (lines) coming from alternating batches. I'd like to print label "1" next to the first 96 lines then "2" next to the second 96 lines and then 1 again and so on.
(I'm putting together data from a machine readout from a plate assay to a vertical list)

I tried to make a counter to count to 96 and then change the number but that of course woks only for first two batches. How can I do it for x number of samples?

```
j = 0
print("Value", "seq", "plate", sep = "\t")
for i in range(0,len(first_line),2):
    if j <= 96:
        plate = 1
    else:
        plate = 2
    print(first_line[i], sequence[j], plate, sep="\t")
    print(first_line[i+1], sequence[j], plate, sep="\t")
    print(second_line[i], sequence[j], plate, sep="\t")
    print(second_line[i+1], sequence[j], plate, sep="\t")
    j += 1
```

What I want to get:

```
        Value   seq             plate
line 95 1.141   EKWAFHQAWIEAA   1
line 96 1.115   GPEAWAAAAFWEI   1
line 97 1.112   LPWFDKAABFWAA   2
line 98 1.181   GSEGESAWAAAWD   2
...
line 272 1.111  EWFIUGHAIWDIW   1
line 273 1.911  AWFNAWAIWFAAW   1
```

Comment: `if j%(2*96)<=96` - will behave the same every `2*96`.

Comment: read about [modulo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_(op%C3%A9ration)), that's what you need

Comment: actually, the operation `//` could also be of great help: `j//96` is equal to zero when `j` is strictly less than 96, then is equal to 1 when `j` is between 96 and  191 and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these great suggestions! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, you have to figure it out for your use case. You need to use the modulus of your number i.e. 96 in your case. Let's say I have to get plate number 1 for first 8 and then 2 for next and then 1 again and so on. So see below:

```
for a in range(1,50):
    if (int(a/9)%2)==0:
        print(f'At index {a}, plate is 1')
    else:
        print(f'At index {a}, plate is 2')
```

Output is:

```
At index 1, plate is 1
At index 2, plate is 1
At index 3, plate is 1
At index 4, plate is 1
At index 5, plate is 1
At index 6, plate is 1
At index 7, plate is 1
At index 8, plate is 1
At index 9, plate is 2
At index 10, plate is 2
At index 11, plate is 2
At index 12, plate is 2
At index 13, plate is 2
At index 14, plate is 2
At index 15, plate is 2
At index 16, plate is 2
At index 17, plate is 2
At index 18, plate is 1
At index 19, plate is 1
At index 20, plate is 1
At index 21, plate is 1
At index 22, plate is 1
At index 23, plate is 1
At index 24, plate is 1
At index 25, plate is 1
At index 26, plate is 1
At index 27, plate is 2
At index 28, plate is 2
At index 29, plate is 2
At index 30, plate is 2
At index 31, plate is 2
At index 32, plate is 2
At index 33, plate is 2
At index 34, plate is 2
At index 35, plate is 2
At index 36, plate is 1
At index 37, plate is 1
At index 38, plate is 1
At index 39, plate is 1
At index 40, plate is 1
At index 41, plate is 1
At index 42, plate is 1
At index 43, plate is 1
At index 44, plate is 1
At index 45, plate is 2
At index 46, plate is 2
At index 47, plate is 2
At index 48, plate is 2
At index 49, plate is 2
```

Do note that for desired output, I am using 9 in the modulus. So, I hope you can figure out the rest in your case.